# Taxonomy Terms That Don't Exist Display Results

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries, register-taxonomy

I am working on a custom post type with an archive at: https://www.bowlertransmissions.com/mmc/

If you click one of the results years, such as '2016' you will then get to a page with two buttons to proceed to results for different events. If you click on the 'AutoCross Challenge' button you then see a list of results for the 2016 AutoCross Challenge. So the slug becomes '/mmc/2016/autocross.' There are no results under 2016 for the Hot Laps Challenge, but if I add the slug 'hot-lap' to 2016 like, '/mmc/2016/hot-lap/', rather than seeing the message that no results exist, I get the results from the 2015 Hot Laps Challenge event.

My custom taxonomies are setup as follows: /mmc/%event-year%/%event-name%/%racing-class%/%vehicle-class%/. All of the pages work as expected, with the exception of pages for taxonomy terms that exist, but don't have any posts for a particular year, event, racing class, or vehicle class.

Going to 'mmc/2017' or just clicking on the 2017 in the archive link above shows the message for no posts properly. Is there a setting when registering my taxonomies that I have missed or is it likely a WP Query issue?

Comment: Have you flush your rewrite rule ? Once please use the Default url and check out the page and then back to the post permalink you used.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that doesn't help.